# Retina display compatibility

Tags: iphone, image-manipulation, iphone-4, retina-display

For our iPhone app, we are using 50 x 50 user image (from facebook). It works fine for iPhone 3G and 3GS but not for iPhone 4 due to its high resolution display. For iPhone 4 we tried to send 100 x 100 (variable height) image but it is not working for obvious reasons. Any thought?

Comment: Images should work on all devices. Show some code.

Comment: Define 'not working' - do you mean no image? Do you mean the images are a bit blocky? Be more specific!

Comment: @deanWombourne and Eiko: The images are getting pixelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* to do anything different for the Retina Display. Using exactly the same image as you have on the older iPhone will work exactly the same.

If you have a higher resolution image that you'd like to display instead, then if you save the file with a `@2x` suffix then, if the device has a Retina display, it will pick that instead. In most cases it should not require any extra code.

Comment: For all the images on the app, we do as you have mentioned. But the user images we use are the profile images of a user from facebook (using facebook conect). And these user images are not saved on our end.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to put a 100x100 image in a space where, on a 3GS, there would be a 50x50 image? In that case I would look at the `contentScaleFactor` which is defined in `UIView` (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentScaleFactor).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. We will try this solution and get back.

Comment: This is still a problem with image on Mobile Feed Dialog - it is device independent and every image looks pixelated on retina devices.  It has been that way for years and Facebook hasn't seem to notice, or does not care to change it.